# Show image from folder based on cell value in MS Excel

Tags: excel, image

I want to show image base on related cell value in Microsoft Excel.

For example,

```
A1 = "mypic.png"        B1 cell should show mypic.png 
A2 = "anotherpic.png"   B2 cell should show anotherpic.png
```

Pictures are in the same directory.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this code you can insert a image in cell `F20` with the path that is stored in cell `A1`. Use the full path like `D:\one.jpg`. Change `Tabelle1` with your sheetname.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim objPicture As Picture
    With Tabelle1.Cells(20, 6) ' Picture starts in cell F20 -> change as you need 
        Set objPicture = .Parent.Pictures.Insert(Tabelle1.Cells(1, 1).Value)
        objPicture.Top = .Top
        objPicture.Left = .Left
        objPicture.Height = 150
        objPicture.Width = 150
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @ katz  Thanks a lot. Its working. But the pic is not displaying in a cell. Rather it's shows in a floting box. Another issue is that cell now should come from variable. Please help.

Comment: @s.k.paul please give more details what you exactly need

Answer (score 0):

I created a template to display image based on cell value, I hope it is useful for users.
I created the Images folder in the same place as the workbook and added the images to this folder. In this folder, if there is an image with the same name as the cell value in column A of the worksheet, it is called and the image is displayed on the image control in column F.

For this, I added a code snippet to the Worksheet_SelectionChange procedure. VBA Codes :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim fso As Object

If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
Image1_Click
Exit Sub
ElseIf Target.Address = "$A$" & ActiveCell.Row Then
Image1.Visible = True
Image1.Top = ActiveCell.Top
Image1.Left = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Left
End If

On Local Error Resume Next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.FileExists(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Images\" & Trim(ActiveCell.Value) & ".jpg") = True Then
Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Images\" & Trim(ActiveCell.Value) & ".jpg")

ElseIf fso.FileExists(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Images\" & Replace(ActiveCell.Value, " ", "") & ".jpg") = True Then
Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Images\" & Replace(ActiveCell.Value, " ", "") & ".jpg")
Else
Image1.Visible = False
End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Explanations and sample file here : [Display image based on cell content](https://eksi30.com/excel-display-image-based-on-cell-value/)